# batch - File last modification time with seconds

Tags: batch-file, batch, timestamp, last-modified, date-modified

I want to know when a file has been modified for the last time.

I can get these infos using the following batch script:

```
FOR %%i IN (myfile) DO SET modif_time=%%~ti
```

The problem is how to get the second of the last modification ? and the command `%~t` returns the date and the time with only hours and minutes.

I can only check the seconds by manually viewing the "property window" file by file.

How can I get the time with seconds in batch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Powershell snippet, you can overcome the console limitation:

```
FOR /f "usebackq tokens=2,3 skip=3" %%i IN (`powershell.exe "& {get-childitem .\foo -force | Select-Object FullName,LastWriteTime}"`) do set modif_time=%%i %%j
```

Also, take a look at this wmic.exe snippet:

```
wmic datafile where name='c:\\temp\\myfile' get LastModified
```

The output looks like:

```
LastModified
20150807125810.203014-420
```

Which may also be suitable for you.

Comment: Lastly there is forfiles:  FORFILES /S /M *.cmd /C "cmd /c echo @fname @ftime"           There may be easier ways to express this, but the above gives a filename, and its time stamp expressed in hh:mm:ss